# Finding Galois corespondance of the polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields

First of all this is a homework problem so please don't post full solutions just hints/advice.

I have polynomial $f(x)=x^4 +x+1 \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. I need to find the Galois group and write up the Galois correspondence between subgroups of the galois group and the subfields of splitting field $L$.

I know how to show that $f(x)$ is irreducible and then I can construct the splitting field as $G(16)\equiv \mathbb{Z}_2/2$ and if $\epsilon$ is one root I know how to show that $\epsilon^2, \epsilon^4, \epsilon^8$ are the other roots. From there the Galois group is generated by the possible images of $\epsilon$ and there is 4 of those which is exactly how much we need by FTGT.
This is all a bit vaguely written but details are less important as I really understand what I did here.

The problem is how to write the Galois Corespondance? I know that all elements of $GF(16)$ which are not 0 are $\epsilon^i$ because the multiplicative group is cyclic and generated by $\epsilon$. However I don't know how to write up the correspondance from here.

Comment: Do you know what is the Galois group of this extension? If you know, you can write it as a symmetry group, and then find out what are its subgroups. After that, observe what are the elements fixed by each subgroup.

Comment: Galois group is the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_4$ generated with automorphisms $\epsilon \rightarrow \epsilon$, $\epsilon \rightarrow \epsilon^2$ etc, at least I think this is it but I am not sure how to get the fixed elements because I am not completely sure how to write up the elements of the field nicely

Comment: Usually a few observations help, but there is a general and a bit silly method: Fix a basis for the vector field $E$ over $F$, and then write $\sigma\in \mathrm{Gal}(E/F)$ in term of a matrix under that basis. From here, you can calculate the eigenvectors of this matrix corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$. The fixed field of a subgroup is the intersection of the fixed fields of its generators.

Comment: Okay that is not a bad idea, and because the galois group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4$ I only need to check what one subgroup does and it has two elements one of which is the identitiy so I just need to do calculations  for one matrix? Thank you!

Comment: In this case, the generator of your subgroup of Gal(GF(16)/GF(2)) is a Frobenius map $F$. Instead of calculating eigenvectors, another method is just write the elements of GF(16) as $p=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$, then solve the equation $F(p)=p$.

Comment: Yes. There is also an alternative method I just recall, see above.